# Java jtree path from leaf node

Tags: java, jtree

There seems to be an issue going from a leaf node to a treepath:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf = ...
DefaultMutableTreeNode[] path = leaf.getPath();
int count0 = path.length; // 4 in my case.
Treepath tpath = new Treepath(path);
int count = tpath.getPathCount(); // this is 1 but it should be 4.
```

This code normally would work properly, but perhaps there is some configuration issue, etc where this could happen?

**Edit**

My configuration uses clojure, which for some reason was calling the Object instead of Object[] constructor, despite an explicit use of into-array. This obscure bug can be worked around by creating a Java class that only calls the Object[] method. This code works properly otherwise.

Comment: I've just tried it and it works correctly for me (though getPath() returns TreeNode, not DefaultMutableTreeNode)

Comment: I am using Clojure and am showing the equivalent java code. Maybe that is what causes it? Or maybe some action at a distance with setting up the tree? It would be nice to stick breakpoints deep into swing functions and see what is going on. Swings strategy of "if it doesn't work, do nothing" is infuriating.

Comment: I don't recall ever encountering Swing behavior like that.  If anything, Swing is clear, consistent and reliable.  Perhaps it would be useful to post the code you actually wrote?